# Improve SORTING performance on long VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a `composite_title` field that is VARCHAR(500) to hold the title of a movie or TV show. Here are a few examples of what it looks like:

```
- The Office, Season 1, Ep. 4 -- The Alliance
- BSG, Season 2, Ep. 3 -- Fragged
- Terminator
```

When I do a sort on the field using:

```
select composite_title from title order by composite_title limit 10
```

It is painfully slow and does not use an index, it uses a file sort. I tried adding something like:

```
ALTER TABLE title ADD INDEX composite_title(10)
```

But it did not improve performance.

What can I do to improve this query?

EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  title   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    341353  Using filesort
```

UPDATE:

The longest tv show in the database is 285 characters long.

From Bill Karwin's solution, this is what worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE `title` ADD `composite_title_for_sorting` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL  DEFAULT '';
UPDATE IGNORE title SET composite_title_for_sorting=composite_title;
```

Now if I sort by the `composite_title_for_sorting`, the query takes 1ms instead of 500ms.

Comment: if you want to get an advice, at least post here the structure of your tables (run a command `show create table title` and paste here the output)

Comment: There's only one column here that matters -- the `composite_title`.

Comment: if you do `select *` and your key is much less than the column used for ordering, then it's very probably that the index doesn't work. Can't say much more without seeing your table or the output of `explain` (which is, by the way, not the sorting query itself, it's a query plan ).

Comment: No, see updated question.

Comment: try doing an `explain ...query` what does it say?

Comment: Updated with the explain.

Comment: What if you put a normal index on the column, instead of `(10)`?

Comment: I can't in mysql -- "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes" (the VARCHAR field must be less than 256 chars)

Comment: So how long is the composite_title field?

Comment: VARCHAR(500) is the length of the composite_title field.

Comment: try my answer and do another `explain`.

Comment: to use index you'll probably have to make your column 255 characters long like the message tells you `ALTER TABLE title MODIFY COlUMN composite_title VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE title ADD INDEX composite_title_index (composite_title);` [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a64/4) I am guessing there isn't a TV show that has a longer name than 255 characters (but who knows I could be wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL should use an index for sorting, but it doesn't seem to like to do that if the index is a prefix index.

And it's clear that you *must* use a prefix index if your varchar length is so long.

So if you want to speed up the ORDER BY, the best way to do this would be to change your column's data type to something that can support a non-prefix index. (Do you really *need* varchar(500) anyway??)

```
ALTER TABLE title MODIFY composite_tite VARCHAR(255), ADD KEY (composite_title);
```

Then you should get this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT composite_title FROM title ORDER BY composite_title\G

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: title
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: composite_title
      key_len: 768    <-- this is the longest key_len allowed for an index
          ref: NULL
         rows: 100
        Extra: Using index
```

---

Another idea is to create a second column to store a shortened version of the string, and then index that column.

If you must do a filesort, then increasing the size of `sort_buffer_size` can possible reduce the dependence on using disk during sorting, which will help performance.

But if you increase sort_buffer_size globally, be aware that it is allocated for every session that's sorting during a query, so if you set it to 1GB or something huge like that, you could blow out your memory at an unpredictable time.

You can change sort_buffer_size on a session-by-session basis. So you could leave it at its default size globally, but in the session where you run this one type of query, increase it.

Comment: The longest TV show here is 285 characters long, so the above solution would chop off some of the data. Any other ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an `explain ...query`. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2572/1).

Then add an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX `helper` ON `title` (`composite_title`);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `title` ADD INDEX helper(`composite_title`);
```

Then retry your query:

```
SELECT composite_title
FROM title 
USE INDEX(helper)
ORDER BY composite_title ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

MySQL optimizer most often does the correct choice. But sometimes it makes a bad choice, or not the best choice. So we force it.

But technically you add a key to the columns you would use `where` on.

---

Maybe some settings for performance instead?

```
Set global thread_cache_size        = 4;
Set global query_cache_size         = 1024*1024*1024;
Set global query_cache_limit        = 768*1024;
Set global query_cache_min_res_unit = 2048;
Set long_query_time                 = 5;
```

---

Or maybe even use [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) with mysql.

- [elasticsearch-river-jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)